# AngularJS unit test with $http request never fires .then() callbacks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to get unit tests running with mocked responses in separate json files. The tests were working when I used $q to return promises resolved manually in my OpsService, but when I tried to make them into actual $http requests to return the actual json files, they no longer worked.

edit: I've tried `$httpBackend.flush()`, `$rootScope.$apply()`, and `$rootScope.$digest()` but none of those seem to resolve the promises.

My service:

```
OpsService.service('OpsService', function ($q, $http) {

    this.get = {
        bigTen : function () {
            // var defer = $q.defer();
            // defer.resolve({"data":{"alltime":125077,"record":{"date":"2016-07-19","count":825},"today":281}});
            // return defer.promise;

            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/jsonMocks/api/big-ten.json'
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log('bigTen data');
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log('ERROR');
                console.log(error);
            });
        },

        dashboardData : function () {
            console.log('blahhhhh');
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/jsonMocks/api/dashboard-data.json'
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log('dasbhoard data');
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log('ERROR');
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    };

    return this;
});
```

My controller:

```
homeModule.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, OpsService) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.loading = {
        topMetrics: true,
        dashboardData: true
    };

    function init() {
        ctrl.topMetricData();

        ctrl.getDashboardData();

        ctrl.initialized = true;
    }

    ctrl.topMetricData = function () {
        ctrl.loading.topMetrics = true;
        console.log('in topMetricData()');
        return OpsService.get.bigTen().then(function (bigTen) {
            console.log('bigTenControllerCallback');

            ctrl.loading.topMetrics = false;
            return bigTen;
        });
    };

    ctrl.getDashboardData = function () {
        ctrl.loading.dashboardData = true;
        console.log('in getDashboardData()');
        return OpsService.get.dashboardData().then(function (response) {
            console.log('getDashboardDataController Callback');

            ctrl.loading.dashboardData = false;
            return dashboardData;
        });
    };

    init();
});
```

My test:

```
describe('home section', function () {
    beforeEach(module('ngMockE2E'));
    beforeEach(module('templates-app'));
    beforeEach(module('templates-common'));
    beforeEach(module('LROps.home'));

    var $rootScope, $scope, $httpBackend, createController, requestHandler;

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector, _$rootScope_, _$controller_, _OpsService_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;

        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

        var bigTenJson = readJSON('jsonMocks/api/big-ten.json');
        console.log(bigTenJson);
        $httpBackend.when('GET', '/jsonMocks/api/big-ten.json')
            .respond(200, { data: bigTenJson });
        // .respond(200, { data: 'test1' });

        var dashboardDataJson = readJSON('jsonMocks/api/dashboard-data.json');
        console.log(dashboardDataJson);
        $httpBackend.when('GET', '/jsonMocks/api/dashboard-data.json')
            .respond(200, { data: dashboardDataJson });
        // .respond(200, { data: 'test2' });

        var $controller = _$controller_;
        createController = function() {
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            return $controller('HomeController', {
                $scope : $scope,
                OpsService : _OpsService_
            });
        };
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('should retrieve big ten data', inject(function () {
        $httpBackend.expect('GET', '/jsonMocks/api/big-ten.json');
        $httpBackend.expect('GET', '/jsonMocks/api/dashboard-data.json');

        // Controller Setup
        var ctrl = createController();

        // Initialize
        $rootScope.$apply();
        $rootScope.$digest();

        expect(ctrl.topMetrics.display.messages.count).toEqual(745);
    }));

});
```

So, none of my console.log() are firing in the .then() callbacks. If I change back to returning a `$q.defer().resolve(response).promise` object, it seems to work fine.

Note: I'm using karma-read-json to read the JSON files and respond accordingly in my tests. As far as I can tell, they're being read properly, it's just the promises aren't being resolved so the .then() callbacks can execute.

Comment: Yes. In the full version of my code, I'm console.log(ing) the json that's read from that file and it's all there. the readJSON() function will throw errors if the file isn't found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing is that each asserted request should be mocked request. The requests should be flushed with `$httpBackend.flush()`, it triggers a digest, `$rootScope.$apply()` and `$rootScope.$digest()` (they duplicate each other) shouldn't be called.

The second thing is that it shouldn't be done in controller spec! Controller is a separate unit that depends on a service, it should be tested in isolation with mocked service. `OpsService` is a different unit.

```
it('should retrieve big ten data', inject(function () {
    $httpBackend.expect('GET', '/jsonMocks/api/big-ten.json').respond(200, ...);
    $httpBackend.expect('GET', '/jsonMocks/api/dashboard-data.json').respond(200, ...);

    OpsService.get.bigTen().then(function (result) {
       expect(result)...
    }, function (err) {
       throw err;
    });
    OpsService.get.dashboardData()...

    $httpBackend.flush();
}));

it('should test a controller', inject(function () {
    var OpsServiceMock = { get: {
       bigTen: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(...),
       dashboardData: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(...)
    } };

    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    var ctrl = $controller('HomeController', {
        $scope : $scope,
        OpsService : OpsServiceMock 
    });

    $rootScope.$digest();

    expect(OpsServiceMock.get.bigTen).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(OpsServiceMock.get.dashboardData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect...
}));
```

Comment: I ended up doing basically this, but I used the actual OpsService instead of mocking it so that I can test the service and the controller at the same time.

Comment: @robert.bo.roth The thing you're describing is called integration test, while the question is about unit tests. UTs are dedicated to testing one units at once and definitely locate a problem to a single unit. UTs are supposed to be be supplemented with ITs, not substituted.

Comment: I get that, I think I just struggle to see the need in unit testing if you have substantial integration testing at the individual modular level. Question though: when I'm spying on these methods in my Service, is there a reason the $http().then() callbacks aren't firing in the service itself? It fires the .then() in the controller, but not in the service. Is that because I've mocked the response?

Comment: Just as an fyi, I'm running a team of only 3 people and just starting to get started with setting up testing "correctly", but figured integration tests for us would be more beneficial right out of the gate because it ensures that our entire application works well together (and will notify us if we make breaking changes that break other modules)

Comment: Ideally I'll be writing unit tests for our Filters, Directives, and individual services, but I'd be integration testing our controllers. At least that's the way I imagined it. So if I wanted to have both unit and integration tests, I'd have 2 different sets of mocked api responses and 2 different sets of tests? Seems like overkill for me, but I understand why it's useful

Comment: Unit tests save time when something brokes and the dev investigates which of the units is to blame. With thoroughly written UTs, ITs can be skipped most of the times and only written for most fragile unit groups (a lot of IT code is pasted from UTs, so ITs are rather inexpensive). E2E tests are responsible for 'putting it all together' plus browser compatibility. It always depends on the app though.

Comment: Cool, it'll definitely be changing until we find our stride, but I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Looking at the [documentation for $httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend), the `expect` and `when` methods don't work together.  They're different options for setting up the backend.

`expect` looks like it adds an expectation that the call will happen, and gives you a .respond() you call call on the result to give what to respond with.

`when` just lets you set up a response for a particular response without actually saying you expect it.

So in your tests the `expect` calls are overwriting the `when` definition you did, and don't return any response because you didn't configure one.

So, I think you can just get rid of the expects and put a `flush` after your controller like so:

```
it('should retrieve big ten data', inject(function () {
    // Controller Setup
    var ctrl = createController();

    $httpBackend.flush();

    // Initialize
    $rootScope.$apply();
    $rootScope.$digest();

    expect(ctrl.topMetrics.display.messages.count).toEqual(745);
}));
```

Or change your `when`s in the `beforeEach` to `expect`s and then you probably won't need the `flush`.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I had tried that too and it says there's no calls to flush: "Error: No pending request to flush !"

I'll update the question. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Hm, that suggests to me that no request was attempted, which is odd.  Do the console.logs from before you make the request show up?

Comment: Yeah, I see every console log except for the ones in .then() callback functions.

Comment: I even have some firing right before the $http() request, and I see those as well so I know it's getting into my service functions, something wacky is going on with my mocked responses i guess?

Comment: So, I commented out my expect('GET') functions, and it didn't complain about unexpected requests. Then, I commented out my when('GET') functions and it started complaining about unexpected responses. Pretty sure that means the service is firing the $http() call, but my mocked response doesn't send back a promise? Maybe I have to wrap my json in a promise?

Comment: I wonder if the root scope digest is triggering the http flush?  That doesn't explain why your callbacks aren't triggering through.
The only real difference I see in my own code is I do $http.get(url), but I don't think that should make a difference here.

Comment: I also don't seem to use the $httpBackend.expect calls at all.  I just do a .when to return my test data, and use flush() to make sure there are no extra pending calls.  The expects on the data in the controller (that should be based on the results) handle checking if it actually made the request.  Perhaps the expects are breaking your when set up earlier?

Comment: I think I see what's going on.  See the edited answer.

Comment: Hmm, tried removing the expects, still no pending requests to flush :( even tried switching to $http.get(). Not sure what's going on